f a graph is $k$- colourable then it is $k$-choosable

Is it true that if a graph is $k$- colourable then it is $k$-choosable?

It is true, right? Because $k$-colourable is a special case when the list is $\{1,\dots,k\}$. But this list is the worst possible list and will give me the maximal bound?
So if a graph is $k$-colourable, it must be $k$- choosable too.

Why is this list the worst possible list?

The statement is false. A counterexample is the complete bipartite graph $K_{2,4}$, which is 2-colorable but not 2-choosable:
If the 2-coclique is given color lists of size two with four different colors, the 4-coclique can be given color lists with combinations of those four colors to prevent a proper coloring.

And, generalizing your example, $K_{n,n^n}$ is $2$-colorable but not $n$-choosable.
